# Casting from Void, storing any type in a Map

Tags: java, casting, void

I want to store different types in a Map like this:

```
public Map< String, Void > common;
MyClass object = new MyClass();
common.put( "Object1", object );
```

and then use it like this:

```
Void object = common.get( "Object1" );
( ( MyClass )object ).runAnyFunction();
```

This only works if I create my own empty class named Void and extends all classes I will put in the Map with Void.  So problem solved, unless...

Isn't there already a Void in Java?  If I don't create my own Void class is still works.  Until I get to the casting where I try to .runAnyFunction().  Maybe if I tried to extend my classes with Void - but that only works with the Void I create, not Java's Void.

It really comes down to if I really need to create my own empty Void class.  Or if I can use Java's own Void?

Comment: `Void` class in Java is a return type marker for Generics and can't be instantiated, in fact the only part of it you can really use is `Void.TYPE` which just returns `Class<Void>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why you don't use Object? All Java classes a directly or indirectly subclasses from Object.

```
public Map< String, Object > common;
```

Comment: It's important to initialise the map too :)

Comment: That's an excellent question! Why I don't use Object? Hmmm...  Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to ask this question but why do you use this solution? I think that every time you want to cast one type to another you should stop and think again about your design.

Really, you want to execute method "runAnyFunction()". What about to create interface

public interface Runner {
    public void  runAnyFunction();

}

now define you map as Map.

then you can say map.get("foo").runAnyFunction() without any casting.

You can create as many as you need implementations of Runner. This is called polymorphism and generally object oriented design.

The next step is probably to reuse one of the existing interfaces, e.g. Runnable or Callable.

I have even written a short article about such usage of existing interfaces: http://java.dzone.com/articles/useful-abuse

Comment: Because I have objects with different interfaces.  If they all had the function runAnyFunction() then it would be ok to do it that way.  However, they have different functions and public variables. But they do have unique ids. And that's why I store all the objects on one Map and call them by their ids...